# Perl negative look ahead

Tags: regex, perl

Here's a small but functional snippet of Perl code:

```
my $content = qq{<img src='h};
if ($content =~ m{src=(?!('*)http://)}) {
   print "Match '$1'\n";
}
else {
   print "No match\n";
}
```

It prints

```
Match '''
```

That is regex ('*) inside negative look ahead has indeed been captured and contains '.

However if I replace the first line with

```
my $content = qq{<img src='i};
```

the script prints

```
Match ''
```

meaning the ' has not been captured despite the fact the entire regex matched.

Can anybody explain what's the difference and how can I make it so that ' is always captured (this is of course a simplification of a real case).

Thanks in advance

**Addendum**

Now this is the whole story for raina77ow. The idea is to replace the contents of the src attribute in the img tag. The following rules apply:

1. If contents starts with ' it must end with '.
2. If contents starts with " it must end with ".
3. Contents can be unquoted.
4. If contents (after possible quote) starts with http:// it should be left intact, other wise the last component of URL (image file name) must be kept and the preceding part must be replaced with smth.

Originally I wanted to use the following regex (which is practically the same you suggested)

```
$content =~ s{<\s*img\s+(.*?)src\s*=\s*(["']*)(?!http://).*?([^/"']+)\2(\s+[^>]+)*>}
             {'<img ' . $1 . 'src="' . 'SMTH' . $3 . '"' . $4 . '>'}sgie;
```

but for some reason it matches the string

[img src='http://qq.com/img.gif' /]

(angle brackets are replaced with square ones).

although it should not because ' is followed by http://. Using

```
$content =~ s{<\s*img\s+(.*?)src\s*=\s*(["'])*(?!http://).*?([^/"']+)\2(\s+[^>]+)*>}
             {'<img ' . $1 . 'src="' . 'SMTH' . $3 . '"' . $4 . '>'}sgie;
```

is also inappropriate as in this case \2 will not match empty string.

Not being able to fix that I decided to look for some workaround. Alas...

Comment: First I would suggest to parse html with a html parser and not with regexes. The `http://` portion is missing in `$content` so it will not match.

Comment: I reiterate using a real HTTP parser. Regular expressions are not well suited for dealing with HTML. I recommend [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

Comment: Thank you for advice, but that does not answer the original question. And then, as I pointed out, th regex does match. The problem is that capturing parentheses are not captured.

Comment: If they answered the original question, they'd be answers rather then comments pointing out that the approach implied by the original question is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: I see. As this is my first question at Stack Overflow, I did not know about the difference between comments and answers. Please excuse.

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel. [Regexes are notoriously unsuitable for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/725418). Use an HTML-parser instead.

Answer (score 4):

Applying the four rules from the question with a robust HTML parser/library:

```
use strictures;
use URI qw();
use Web::Query qw();
my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html(<<'HTML');
<html><head></head><body>
<img src='http://example.com'>
<img src="http://example.com">
<img src=http://example.com>
<img src='foo/bar/baz.png'>
<img src="foo/bar/baz.png">
<img src=foo/bar/baz.png>
</body></html>
HTML

$w->find('img')->each(sub {
    my (undef, $img) = @_;
    my $u = URI->new($img->attr('src'));
    unless ($u->scheme) {   # skip absolute URIs
        $u->path_segments('SMTH', ($u->path_segments)[-1]);
        $img->attr('src', $u);
    }
});
print $w->html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's quite easy to fix it:

```
my $content = qq{<img src='h};
if ($content =~ m{src=('*)(?!http://)}) {
   print "Match '$1'\n";
}
else {
   print "No match\n";
}
```

But explaining the bug you described (and I think that's really a bug of Perl regex engine - why `('*)` should match differently in `'h` and `'i` cases?) is another story. )

**UPDATE:** forgive me for submitting to the Cthulhu ways, but this code might do what you asked for:

```
sub correct { # just an example
  my $orig = shift;
  $orig =~ s/\.gif$/\.jpg/;
  return $orig;
}

my $img = "<img src='http://localhost.com/pic.gif' />";
$img =~ s{
  (< \s* img \s+ src \s* = \s*)
  (["']?)
  ([^ '">]+)
  \2
}{ 
  $1 . $2 . ( substr($3, 0, 7) eq 'http://' ?  $3  : correct $3 ) . $2
}xe;

print $img;
```

Still, those who said that it's better to use HTML Parser, any of them, got the biggest clue, I think. )

Comment: For the reason that would lead us too far astray this solution is not suitable. If you could tell me this other story I'd be delighted.

Comment: Then please describe why this solution is not suitable, won't you? Anyway, the point was not in the code, but rather the decision to use _two_ 'lookups' instead of a single one.

Comment: OK, here's the whole story. The idea is to replace the contents of the src atrribute of an img tag. The rules should be:

Comment: Pardon the whole story is too long, it does not fit the comment area.

Comment: Thanks. That would indeed work. And yes, I agree that HTML should be parsed rather than regexed. However I had to make a quick and dirty patch. This one would do. But having the answer why lookahead behaves strangely would also be great. Am I asking for too much? :)

Comment: Well, I'd recommend creating another question specifically for that issue - it's really interesting. I have some suspicions about what cause that bug, but I don't know Perl's internals well enough to prove them. )

Comment: Actually the queastion WAS about this issue. Frankly, I don't know how to rephrase it more to the point :)